# How to find email domains using proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

In mysql this would look like: 
substring_index(email, '@', -1)

But I can't seem to find if a function like this is available in SAS proc sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to work

```
data _null_;
x='rxx@gmail.com';
dom=substr(x,findc(x,'@'));
put dom;
run;
```

Comment: you are the one man! this worked. My rep isn't higher but consider this +1'ed

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Use FINDW to find the position of @ and SUBSTR to return the remainder?

Comment: sounds like it could work - haven't been able to write the exact function using those two functions yet though.

Comment: In other languages such as SQLite, where FINDW is called instr(), it'd be something like substr('mail@server',1+instr('mail@server','@'))

Comment: here's where I am so far - which seems to pull the domain minus the .com piece: scan(substr(email,index(email, "@")),1)

Comment: Can you try substr(email,1+findw(email,"@"))